C socket program stuck at listen()
I am trying to learn socket programming in C and i was trying to setup a basic TCP connection between client and server however in my server.c my code is seemingly just stuck at listen(). It does not execute the next lines and it also doesnt return the error message.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    char *ip="127.0.0.1";
    int port =5566;
    int server_sock,client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr,clientaddr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char buffer[1024];
    int n;
    server_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(server_sock<0){
        perror("[-]Socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] TCP server socket created\n");

    memset(&serveraddr,'\0',sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port=port;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
    n=bind(server_sock,(struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr,sizeof(serveraddr));
    if(n<0){
        perror("[-]Bind error");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+] TCP SOCKET BOUND to port %d\n",port);
    n=listen(server_sock,5);
    if(n<0){
        perror("listen error\n");exit(1);
    }
    printf("server listening");
    while(1){
        addr_size=sizeof(clientaddr);
        client_sock=accept(server_sock,(struct sockaddr*) &clientaddr,&addr_size);
        printf("[+]Client Connected.\n");
    }
    

}

This is my current server.c
n=listen(server_sock,5); It doesn't execute past this line. In my client.c the code is similar however i am getting a bind erorr

however i am getting a bind erorr Please show the actual message, and the code that causes the error.

Your stdout stream has probably been set to line buffered mode by default, so is expecting a newline to be written to the stream before it flushes the buffer contents to the underlying file descriptor. Adding fflush(stdout); calls will force the buffered contents to be flushed to the underlying file descriptor.

When your program reports a bind error, it exits immediately afterward.  I don't see how it could both report a bind error and reach the listen() call on the same run.

You're not setting the port correctly, btw

serveraddr.sin_port=port; -> serveraddr.sin_port=htons(port); Also, your loop needs to call close(client_sock); if accept() is successful.


"my code is seemingly just stuck at listen()" That's an illusion. It is not. Make sure there is a newline (\n) at the end of every message you print and run again.

– Comment from n. m. could be an AI
He is correct

As requested, please show your client.c to shed more light on the error.
Typically, you don't need to call bind() at the client side at all, a connect() should suffice. Not sure if this is what you meant.
If your client calls bind() for the same port on the same machine then you'll find that the first program to run (client or server) will prevent the other from binding successfully.
The missing htons() calls that were also noted above may not be critical as long as the client & server match. If you use htons() on one side then you must use it on the other.
Extend your debug print of "server listening" to emit the sin_port and add a \n at the end, and you should see something more interesting.
